# Can't Install Composer Correctly -

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I run fin composer install to get composer installed, but I keep running into this error message:

In Git.php line 484:

Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'https://bee...nka:Wes...231@git.drupalcode.org/project/embed_block.git' '/home/docker/.composer/cache/vcs/https--
-git.drupalcode.org-project-embed-block.git/'

Cloning into bare repository '/home/docker/.composer/cache/vcs/https---git.drupalcode.org-project-embed-block.git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.drupalcode.org/project/embed_block.git/': Could not resolve host: git.drupalcode.org

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [...]

Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.64.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

I feel like I get most of the install but after about 5 minutes, I keep running into this. I'm not sure what is the problem. Before when I did a composer install for other projects, I didn't need to go to GitHub to get it, it just started downloading and installing. But now it sends me to GitHub, where I use my credentials to get it, unsuccessfully.

I also tried to get it directly from getcomposer.org. After running the first line in the install, I get:

PHP Warning:  copy(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled in Command line code on line 1

Warning: copy(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  copy(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1

Warning: copy(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): Failed to open stream: operation failed in Command line code on line 1

Warning: copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): Failed to open stream: operation failed in Command line code on line 1
FNM-S102305:~ beesonka$ php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e21205b207c3ff031906575712edab6f13eb0b361f2085f1f1237b7126d785e826a450292b6cfd1d64d92e6563bbde02') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
PHP Warning:  hash_file(composer-setup.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Warning: hash_file(composer-setup.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
Installer corruptPHP Warning:  unlink(composer-setup.php): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Warning: unlink(composer-setup.php): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Comment: `Could not resolve host: git.drupalcode.org` - that does not look like a problem with Composer itself. Also, you should not use Composer while XDebug is enabled

Comment: @NicoHaase OK, if it's not a composer problem, and it seems to download a lot of it, not sure what it could be. Is there a way to get composer installed without using GitHub?

Comment: Please share more details. Do you try to install Drupal or Composer? Also, `git.drupalcode.org` does not look like you're using Github after all. And finally: did you try to disable XDebug?

Comment: @NicoHaase I got XDebug to turn off. I have Drupal and I need composer as part of the install. I just tried to go to getcomposer.org/download and get it from there. After running the first line of code for the install, I get this message: PHP Warning: copy(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled in Command line code on line 1

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. That's a completely new error message

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while changing php version on my Windows. Hope this could help someone. php.ini didn't have right extensions and I just had to uncomment:

extension_dir = "ext"
extension=openssl